# Temporarily setting an environment variable in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

I do something like this in bash to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for only one command, without leaving it in the environment afterwards:

```sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/geometry ./ex3_3.out
```

What's the equivalent in tcsh? If I use `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/geometry; ./ex3_3.out` it leaves `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set, which is not what I want.

Comment: BTW, this is probably a question that should properly  be on [unix.se], not SO, since it's about general-purpose syntax that's relevant to all end-users of tcsh, not primarily or exclusively to folks doing software development. (I also removed the `bash` tag, since it's knowledge of tcsh rather than knowledge of bash that's relevant).

Answer (score 4):

```
/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/geometry ./ex3_3.out
```

...should work everywhere, since it's relying on `/usr/bin/env` rather than any shell-specific syntax or builtin.

Comment: It doesn't work. In bash I'm able to link shared object file (*.so) to my ex3_3.out program but I don't know how to do in tcsh.

Comment: Please be more specific about "doesn't work" -- what's the specific error message you get instead? If it's invoking a tcsh builtin by the same name, try `/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/geometry ./ex3_3.out` instead.

Comment: BTW, linking in shared libraries isn't something bash *or* tcsh has any responsibility for -- the shell just sets up the environment variables; it's the dynamic loader (`ld.so`, on Linux) that's responsible for reading them.

Comment: Good deal -- edited the answer to specify that fully-qualified path.

Comment: I do /usr/bin/env and now it's ok:).

Comment: Glad to hear! Since your problem is fixed, consider clicking the checkmark next to the answer; having accepted an answer will mark the question solved.